# Laravel 4: Link to Destroy Method

Tags: laravel-4, laravel-routing

Is there any way to change a method to DELETE when you are simply linking to the controller's @destroy method?

The following does not work:

```
$s = '<a href="'.action('CollegeController@destroy', $college->getId()).'" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></a>';
```

Now if I do this with the @edit method it takes me to the appropriate method because edit uses GET. I'm assuming this has something to do with routing but I am not quite sure how to go about it and haven't found a clear answer yet.

Comment: It's not wise to use `GET` requests for any modifications of your resources, deleting being definitely one of them. As per HTTP ref: *the convention has been established that the GET and HEAD methods SHOULD NOT have the significance of taking an action other than retrieval* - http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using resourceful routing and want to access the DELETE method in your controller, you'll need to use a form.

`echo Form::open(array('url' => 'foo/bar', 'method' => 'delete'))`

Will open a Laravel form and include a hidden field called `_method` with a value of `DELETE` - and this will trigger the delete method you seek.

Comment: Right that makes sense I was wondering how I was supposed to change the method without having a form. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've been in the same situation as you and doing some research i found this than might help you like it did me

```
Form::macro('delete', function ($url, $button_label = 'Delete', $form_parameters = array(), $button_options = array()) {

    if (empty($form_parameters)) {
        $form_parameters = array(
            'method' => 'DELETE',
            'class' => 'delete-form',
            'url' => $url
        );
    } else {
        $form_parameters['url'] = $url;
        $form_parameters['method'] = 'DELETE';
    };
    $button_options['type'] = 'submit';
    return Form::open($form_parameters)
    . Form::button($button_label, $button_options)
    . Form::close();
});
```

It can be used in blade templates by using this

{{Form::delete('route.to.destroy.method','Button Text',['class'=>'btn btn-danger'])}}

create a file called macro.php and inculde it into the bootstrap file

Comment: The only issue is that I need to call this within the controller. From what I understand that's not possible correct?

Comment: Well all it does it generated html so it should do what your trying to do. Actions will always be GET requests have you tried using named routes instead?